# React Event Bubbling: Finding the target Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, event-bubbling

I have a `<ul>` Component wrapping some `<li>` Components. I want to avoid adding an `onClick` handler to each `li` and instead use a single handler on the `ul` and capture the bubbled events.

What is the correct way of determining / assigning the clicked Component from the bubbled event?

```
class ListItemComponent extends React.Component {
    public render() {
        return (
            <li>Foo</li>
        )
    }
}

class ListComponent extends React.Component {
    private handleClick(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        // Determine clicked component, or index etc … ?
    }

    public render() {
        const items = this.props.items.map((x, i) => {
            <ListItemComponent active=“false” key={i} />    
        })
        return (
            <ul onClick={this.handleClick} />
                { items }
            </ul>
        )
    }   
}
```

Comment: You can't pass `event` around in React.  pass the `event.target` directly into your handleClick function.

Comment: I'm not sure what solution you are suggesting. Can you provide an example? In the example I gave I certainly can access the event.

Comment: I'm just saying that when you pass event around you really get SyntheticEvent, which is more difficult to deal with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to add a `data-index` attribute to each child which can be used to identify the component.

This avoids adding multiple event listeners while also avoiding the overhead of multiple `ref` callbacks to obtain the child DOM elements:

```
class ListItemComponent extends React.Component {
    public render() {
        return (
            <li data-index={this.props.index}>Foo</li>
        )
    }
}

class ListComponent extends React.Component {
    private handleClick(event) {
        const activeIndex = event.target.getAttribute('data-index');
        this.setState({ activeIndex });
    }

    public render() {
        const active = this.state.activeIndex;
        const items = this.props.items.map((x, i) => {
            <ListItemComponent active={i === active} key={i} index={i} />    
        })
        return (
            <ul onClick={this.handleClick} />
                { items }
            </ul>
        )
    }   
}
```